# Differential Calculus by Piskunov (Problem 41, Chapter 5)

Tags: calculus

This is a simple problem to find the maxima/minima of a function. However, I am not able to construct the volume of the cone as of the radius $R$ of the sphere. The question is as follows -

Find the height of a right cone with with least volume circumscribed about a given sphere of radius $R$.

[image: Construction of right cone circumscribing a sphere]

$v(h)=\frac{1}{3}\pi{r^2}{h}$

I am not able to find an equation that will help me eliminate $r$.

Answer (score 2):

$$h=r\tan(\theta)$$$${R\over h-R}=\cos(\theta)$$ Sustituting value of $r(=R\{\cot(\theta)+\csc(\theta)\})$ from here into volume$$V={1\over 3}\pi r^2h={1\over 3}\pi r^3\tan(\theta)={1\over 3}\pi R^3(\cot(\theta)+\csc(\theta))^3\tan(\theta)$$
Now differentiate w.r.t $\theta$ and get your answer

Answer (score 1):

Note that the angle bisector at $C$ passes through $O$. It follows that
$$h=r\tan\theta,\qquad r=R\cot{\theta\over2}\ ,$$
and this gives
$$V={\pi\over3} r^2 h={\pi\over3}R^3\cot^3{\theta\over2}\tan\theta={\pi\over3}R^3\>{2\over\tan^2{\theta\over2}\bigl(1-\tan^2{\theta\over2}\bigr)}\ .$$
Letting $\tan^2{\theta\over2}=:u\in[0,1[\>$ we have to maximize $u(1-u)$ in the interval $[0,1]$, which takes place at $u={1\over2}$. The minimal volume of such a cone therefore is
$$V_{\min}={\pi\over3}R^3\>{2\over{1\over2}\bigl(1-{1\over2}\bigr)}={8\pi\over3}R^3\ .$$